# I cannot print characters to the screen using printf

Tags: c

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 and for some odd reason I am not able to print characters to the display using printf. I have been running test code and it certainly is not allowing me to print characters at all. I am capable of printing integers to the screen just fine. I have never ran into an issue like this before. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char item;

    printf("Test character # 1: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &item);
    printf("Test character entered = %c\n\n", item);


    return (0);

}
```

The output is simply this:

```
Test character entered =
```

It just shows a blank no matter what.

I have tried using `fflush(stdout)` and it didn't matter.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might try next? I think I will try to run this on my Mac just to make sure I am not doing something incorrect. Also, I will try to have `printf` print a string out using `%s` to see if that will work.

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: UPDATE: I did try to print a string using %s and it works just fine. So this issue is only limited to characters in printf using %c. I wonder if there is an issue with the scanf_s() function? This is my first time using that function and in fact, Microsoft claims it is an error if I try to use scanf() and it will not let me compile my code.

Comment: `%c` and `%s` of `scanf_s` need  size. E.g  `scanf_s("%c", &item, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx `scanf_s()`, requires a buffer size for all input parameters of c, C, s, S. Try changing your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char item;

    printf("Test character # 1: ");
    scanf_s("%c", &item, 1);
    printf("Test character entered = %c\n\n", item);


    return (0);

}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The documentation says, "Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []." Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This solved it! I am trying not to be frustrated at Microsoft right now but I am disappointed that Microsoft declares that scanf() is an error and states I must use scanf_s, but then it changes the way scanf has always worked for years. Ok, enough whining :) Sorry.

Comment: I also wanted to add that when you use scanf_s without declaring a buffer size for integers, it works just fine! It seems to only require a buffer size declared for non-integer items only.